# Selecting data by the name (grep function)

Tags: r

So, I want to select some rows using the grep function but it's not working properly for me:

That's the code I used:

```
set.seed(2)
tbl_bio <- tbl_reo[grepl("Biotin", tbl_reo$modifications), , drop = FALSE] ## selecting rows from column "modifications" with string Biotin - that works good

tbl_bio1 <- tbl_bio[grep1("BiotinControl1_2", tbl_bio$variable), , drop = TRUE]
tbl_bio2 <- tbl_bio1[grepl("BiotinControl2", tbl_bio1$variable), , drop = TRUE]
tbl_bio3 <- tbl_bio2[grepl("BiotinControl3", tbl_bio2$variable), , drop = TRUE]
```

The problem is with three other lines of code because I set the drop to TRUE so I thought that I just delete the rows which include strings I mentioned. 
After running such code I don't have any data. How to delete the rows (drop) which include "BiotinControl1_2" and so on. 
Can it be done in one function or I have to write 3 different codes like I did ?

Comment: Does your first row says `grep1` and not `grepl`?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the drop argument. From the `?"["` help page: drop: "For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement."

Comment: How about e.g. `tbl_bio3 <- tbl_bio2[-grep("BiotinControl3", tbl_bio2$variable), ]`?

Comment: Do you really need `grep`? Please read `?Extract` and `?subset`.

Comment: I don't need the grep but that's the function I thought that I know how to use. I'll read about extract and subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using some fake data.  Hope it helps.

```
df <- structure(list(mod = c("b", "d", "b", "e", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
    "b", "b", "b", "f", "d", "f", "d", "f", "f", "c", "a", "b"), 
    var = c("K", "L", "H", "G", "J", "I", "G", "K", "H", "G", 
    "L", "G", "K", "K", "J", "L", "I", "H", "H", "H"), x = c(47L, 
    18L, 24L, 91L, 27L, 23L, 97L, 19L, 73L, 20L, 90L, 25L, 92L, 
    98L, 37L, 62L, 54L, 52L, 49L, 56L)), .Names = c("mod", "var", 
    "x"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

# select all rows with variable mod equal to string "b"
df[df$mod=="b", ]
# select all rows with variable var NOT equal to string "I", "J", "L"
df[!(df$var %in% c("I", "J", "L")), ]
# select all rows with variable mod equal to string "b" AND variable var NOT equal to string "I", "J", "L"
df[df$mod=="b" & !(df$var %in% c("I", "J", "L")), ]
```